# POST request fails "The CSRF token could not be verified" (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-requests

I have been trying to log on to this site with the python requests module, but I keep seeing "The CSRF token could not be verified". I have tried doing what other answers said but it doesn't seem to work.

```
client = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.biopharmcatalyst.com/account/login/'
client.get(url)
token = client.cookies['CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN']


headers = {'Cookie':token}

print(token)


login_data = {'loginName':'login',
    'password':'pass',
              'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN':token}
    

r1=client.post(url,data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=url))



print(r1.text)
```

I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong here. When I go to the html, I see a different value for the CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN than what the cookie shows under headers.

Comment: Is the site using Django or Flask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page is setting the CRSF token using JS and the DOM.

You will need to parse the initial GET request to get the token and then pass that to your login.

Something like the following:

```py
import re

client = requests.Session()
url = 'https://www.biopharmcatalyst.com/account/login/'
r = client.get(url)

match = re.search(r'window.csrfTokenValue = "(.*?)";', r.text)
if match:
   crsf = match.group(1)

login_data = {
  'loginName':'login',
  'password':'pass',
  'CRAFT_CSRF_TOKEN':crsf}
```

Handling the headers and so forth will be different depending on what happens after you get the login (I don't have an account).